# Instantiating Employee variable that references a new Faculty

Tags: java

Instantiate an Employee variable that references a new Faculty. what does it meaning ?
I am confuse in that.

Here is class hiraricy.

```
interface Rules 
Employee implements Rules
Faculty extends Employee
```

Answer (score 4):

The class hierarchy is wrong. A faculty IS NOT an employee, so there should be no inheritance hierarchy.

The sentence doesn't mean much beause instantiating a variable doesn't mean anything. I think that what it means is: Create a new instance of the class Employee. An employee should reference an instance of Faculty. So it should have a field of type Faculty.

EDIT:

based on the complete instructions, the class hierarchy is right. But the Faculty class is extremely badly named. It should be named "FacultyMember" or "Professor" instead (since that's what it is).

The wording is also not very well chosen. What "Instantiate an Employee variable that references a new Faculty" means in this context is:

```
Employee employee = new Faculty(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.faculty = new Faculty();
```